# Need direction with modifying / creating jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, animation, slideshow

I'm looking to create a slider and have been given some specifics on how it should look / operate:  [Link to the original specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKMou.png)

Each image has a circle for a placeholder (12 images total) and has a timer which counts down on each slide represented by a circle filling around on the outside.  When the timer finishes it moves on to the next picture.

When a circle is clicked it will pause that slide and clicking again on that circle will resume the slideshow.

My question is:  to accomplish this, should I try to find an existing asset and modify it or start from scratch?

If starting from scratch makes more sense, is there a specific place I should start looking first to figure out how to create my own jquery slideshow?  Or will it take overall knowledge of jquery animations to create this?

What functions could come in handy in the creation of this?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is really fit for StackOverflow as it may get more opinions than real answers. Saying that, my opinion would be to check out something like [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/). I've made some pretty customisable slideshows using it as the base. I can't/won't tell you how to specifically get your functionality but if you get stuck with an issue in your implementation, then you can post another question here and we can help you out. :)

Comment: Alright, thanks.  I'll take a look at Cycle2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone's curious, this at least seems like a good source for starting off creating a jquery slideshow from scratch: http://www.barrelny.com/blog/building-a-jquery-slideshow-plugin-from-scratch/